# remove too close time elements from a json array

Tags: arrays, json, ruby

I am having an array of json object which contain timing and data.

Basically, each element, contain timing, id and user as below

```
[
    {
    "id": "abc",
    "ts": "2017-08-17T20:42:12.557229",
    "userid": "seb"
    },
    {
    "id": "def",
    "ts": "2017-08-17T20:42:52.724773",
    "userid": "seb"
    },
    {
    "id": "ghi",
    "ts": "2017-08-17T20:42:53.724773",
    "userid": "matt"
    },
    {
     "id": "jkl",
     "ts": "2017-08-17T20:44:50.557229",
     "userid": "seb"
    },
    {
     "id": "mno",
     "ts": "2017-08-17T20:44:51.724773",
     "userid": "seb"
    },
    {
      "id": "pqr",
      "ts": "2017-08-17T20:50:52.724773",
      "userid": "seb"
    }
]
```

My goal is to remove object too close to each other if the userid is the same. if the time difference is below 2 sec, we remove the element.

From the list, I should get the list

```
[
    {
    "id": "abc",
    "ts": "2017-08-17T20:42:12.557229",
    "userid": "seb"
    },
    {
    "id": "def",
    "ts": "2017-08-17T20:42:52.724773",
    "userid": "seb"
    },
    {
    "id": "ghi",
    "ts": "2017-08-17T20:42:53.724773",
    "userid": "matt"
    },
    {
      "id": "pqr",
      "ts": "2017-08-17T20:50:52.724773",
      "userid": "seb"
    }
]
```

even if the 2 objects for user matt and seb are too close to each other below 2seconds, we have to keep the element as it's not the same user

```
"ts": "2017-08-17T20:42:52.724773" for seb
```

and

```
"ts": "2017-08-17T20:42:53.724773" for matt
```

Any idea how to code it in Ruby ? I always compared the element n to the n-1 and delete the n-1 if needed

Comment: What have you tried so far and what difficulty are you experiencing with it? If you need a place to start, you have an [Array](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html) of [Hash](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html) objects and need to check for a difference in [Time](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Time.html), could try looking through the documentation for those classes, and any parent classes or included modules, and see if anything jumps out at you as maybe being helpful.

Comment: What is the desired return value if the array were `[{id: "abc", 
ts: 2017-08-17T20:40:00.0, userid: "seb"}, {id: "def", ts: 2017-08-17T20:40:01.1, userid: "seb"},  {id: "ghi", ts: 2017-08-17T20:40.02.2,  userid: "seb"}]`?  I assume  the keys are symbols, so quotes are not needed, and that the times are `Time` or `DateTime` objects, so quotes are not applicable there either.

Comment: Is it correct that you want to remove _both_, id `'jkl'` and id `'mno'`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland although Ruby can parse `"key": "value"` nowadays, I assume that this is a JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'time'

result = []

timestamps = {}

data.each do |item|
  ts = timestamps[item['userid']]  

  if ts.nil? or Time.parse(item['ts']) - Time.parse(ts) > 2
    result.push(item)
    timestamps[item['userid']] = item['ts']
  end
end

puts result
```

Answer (score 0):

What about the code below?

It changes the order of the records, but you could re-sort them if needed.

```rb
require 'date'

def time_elapsed_in_seconds(start_time, end_time)
  ((end_time - start_time) * 24 * 60 * 60).to_i
end

def too_close?(first_time, second_time, threshold = 2)
  time_elapsed_in_seconds(first_time, second_time) < threshold
end

def datetimes(a, b)
  return [DateTime.parse(a), DateTime.parse(b)]
end

def should_reject_record?(record, next_record)
  datetimes = datetimes(record[:ts], next_record[:ts])
  record[:userid] == next_record[:userid] && too_close?(*datetimes)
end

def filter_records(records)
  sorted = records.sort_by{|record| [record[:userid], record[:ts]] }
  sorted.select.with_index do |record, index|
    previous_record = sorted[index-1]
    record == sorted.first || !should_reject_record?(previous_record, record)
  end
end

records = [
    {
    "id": "abc",
    "ts": "2017-08-17T20:42:12.557229",
    "userid": "seb"
    },
    {
    "id": "def",
    "ts": "2017-08-17T20:42:52.724773",
    "userid": "seb"
    },
    {
    "id": "ghi",
    "ts": "2017-08-17T20:42:53.724773",
    "userid": "matt"
    },
    {
     "id": "jkl",
     "ts": "2017-08-17T20:44:50.557229",
     "userid": "seb"
    },
    {
     "id": "mno",
     "ts": "2017-08-17T20:44:51.724773",
     "userid": "seb"
    },
    {
      "id": "pqr",
      "ts": "2017-08-17T20:50:52.724773",
      "userid": "seb"
    }
]

puts filter_records(records)
```